# Add a 'crash screen'?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, crash

I have an alarm app and it should never crash, but in the event that it does (especially in beta testing phase) is there a way to  show a crash image? So an image that it goes to if the app crashes (but it stays in the app)? That way if it were worst case scenario and were to crash during the night, they may wake up, see the app's crashed screen and be saved from sleeping in.

Comment: Does your crash screen sound an alarm to wake the user up?

Comment: check for the usage of the tag [xcode]: stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use local notifications, and set one when the user sets the alarm, they'll get woken up matter what. If your app hasn't crashed then you can stop the notification from showing and raise the alarm in your own way. But if the app crashes or the user switches app then an alert view will pop up and you can set the sound to be made.

Comment: Nice alternate solution. Good idea!